# Allowing ssh in iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I am doing `iptables` firewall configuration. Actually, I need to allow `ssh` connection only from particular IP. But, It is blocking the ssh connection.

I used the below commands.

```
sat:~# iptables -F
sat:~# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s src_ip_address -d my_ip_address --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sat:~# iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
sat:~# iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  src_ip_address       my_ip_address       tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

If I try to connect from **src_ip_address** to **my_ip_address**, it is blocking the connection. Even, It is blocking from **my_ip_address** to **src_ip_address** . I haven't put any rules for OUTPUT chain.

What is wrong with my commands?

How to allow ssh in iptables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allow connections which are established as well with `iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state=established,related`.

Comment: Tried this: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s src_ip_address -d my_ip_address --dport 22 -m state --state=NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`. Still it is blocking.

Comment: @sat That is not what was specified in this answer.

Comment: I'd suggest that you make very simple rules first without combining too much into one entry. Allow established and related on one rule, then allow new on another. After that tighten the related/established rule bit by bit until you get a blocking situation again. Making baby steps will help you to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Okay..I will try.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to put combine a logging rule into a rule which does the dropping. Something like this: `iptables -N drop-and-log ; iptables -A drop-and-log -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES" --log-tcp-sequence --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options ; iptables -A log-and-drop -j DROP ; iptables -A INPUT -j drop-and-log` .